# Matlab: Suppressing the warning dialog box of uiputfile

Tags: matlab, save, dialog

I want to use `uiputfile` to get file path to insert some sheets to Excel file but a warning dialog box is displayed when existing file is selected. As I am not going to overwrite file and my code only insert sheets to existing file, the prompt seems useless. Is there any way to suppress it?

Comment: If I understand correctly, why not use `uigetfile` instead?

Comment: Because, there are two cases: the first case is when chosen file is not existing and it should be created, and the second case is when chosen file is existing and some sheets should be inserted to the file. It is not only opening an existing file and inserting some sheets.

Comment: ah never mind, you're right :) Now I doubt you can suppress the warning; `uiputfile` seems to be using the native OS file chooser dialog (at least on Windows), and MATLAB does not expose a way to specify such a setting

Answer (score 2):

There is a long discussion of this here: [UIPUTFILE functionality](http://comp.soft-sys.matlab.narkive.com/PYJuz4f5/uiputfile-functionality)

Their proposal is this simple "java hack" function. This achieves the desired effect of removing the warning dialog, but it also lacks all the customization of the built-in uigetfile/uiputfile:

```
parframe = com.mathworks.hg.peer.utils.DialogUtilities.createParentWindow;
obj = javahandle_withcallbacks.com.mathworks.mwswing.MJFileChooser;
obj.showOpenDialog(parframe);
filename = char(obj.getSelectedFile);
delete(obj)
```